# Getting OperationResult when ResultUrl is not in response object?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am turning to the community as I haven't found anything in the official documentation.

As the title says, I am having troubles fetching the operation result. I am creating an operation by calling the [Project - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST endpoint. The HTTP call is responding with the operation reference, as the operation is successfully queued. While the operation is running (States `NotSet`, `Queued`, `InProgress`), I am polling the operation at an 300 ms interval. After several seconds, the operation results in a success state.

As the operation was successful, I would expect that the `resultUrl` property of the Operation is populated with the URL pointing to the created resource (in my case in the form of `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectId}?api-version=6.0`). However, `resultUrl` is not part of the response of the GET call at all.

Is there anything I am missing or misinterpreting? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not clear in your question. If you create a new project, you know its name. The URL to projects is stable:

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects/{projectNAME}?api-version=6.0`

You can get [ProjectState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#projectstate) in the answer and any over information like the project URL ([TeamProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#teamproject)).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the approach that I have taken now. It is still odd though that the `resultUrl` is not populated.